# How to pass POST parameters to open a webpage in browser?

Tags: firefox, search

We can open a website with **GET** parameters in the browser as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'enter username'
read username

firefox "https://github.com/${username}"
```

This comes in handy because I can now visit any user's github page with just a command and then entering their username. Similarly we can make a shell script to search Google with our passed query in the parameters.

How do I open a website which requires **POST** parameters to be passed so that I can directly visit the website from the terminal?

Take for example, https://www.startpage.com . If POST request passing is possible then we can directly search our query from terminal.

**Note: Not looking for answers based on curl to retrieve data, but answers based on firefox or any other browser to visit the website**

---

Any other way better than `Selenium` because user would not have control over low level data being passed in POST request like `User-Agent`, `lang`, and some other header parameters. User would be bound to only UI options if using Selenium and these low level header can't be modified according to need.

---

`xdotool` would be costly because user would have to count how many times to do <kbd>Tab</kbd> in order to reach the particular form field, and then loop <kbd>Tab</kbd> that many times before typing something in there. It also doesn't give me the ability to change low level POST parameters like `User-Agent` , `lang` , etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create a temporary auto-submitting HTML page, point the browser to that page, and after a couple of seconds, you remove the temporary HTML file as it is no longer needed. In script form:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create an autodeleted temporary directory.
Work="$(mktemp -d)" || exit 1
trap "cd / ; rm -rf '$Work'" EXIT

# Create a HTML page with the POST data fields,
# and have it auto-submit when the page loads.
cat > "$Work/load.html" <<END
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>&hellip;</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function dosubmit() { document.forms[0].submit(); }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="dosubmit();">
  <form action="https://www.startpage.com/do/asearch" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
   <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="web">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="process_search">
   <input type="hidden" name="language" value="english">
   <input type="hidden" name="engine0" value="v1all">
   <input type="hidden" name="query" value="&#34;Nominal Animal&#34;">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
END

# Load the generated file in the browser.
firefox "file://$Work/load.html"

# Firefox returns immediately, so we want to give it a couple
# of seconds to actually read the page we generated,
# before we exit (and our page vanishes).
sleep 2
```

---

Let's change the above, so that we do a StartPage search on whatever string(s) are supplied on the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create an autodeleted temporary directory.
Work="$(mktemp -d)" || exit 1
trap "cd / ; rm -rf '$Work'" EXIT

# Convert all command-line attributes to a single query,
# escaping the important characters.
rawAmp='&'   ; escAmp='&amp;'
rawLt='<'    ; escLt='&lt;'
rawGt='>'    ; escGt='&gt;'
rawQuote='"' ; escQuote='&#34;'
QUERY="$*"
QUERY="${QUERY//$rawAmp/$escAmp}"
QUERY="${QUERY//$rawQuote/$escQuote}"
QUERY="${QUERY//$rawLt/$escLt}"
QUERY="${QUERY//$rawGt/$escGt}"

# Create a HTML page with the POST data fields,
# and have it auto-submit when the page loads.
cat > "$Work/load.html" <<END
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>&hellip;</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function dosubmit() { document.forms[0].submit(); }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="dosubmit();">
  <form action="https://www.startpage.com/do/asearch" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
   <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="web">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="process_search">
   <input type="hidden" name="language" value="english">
   <input type="hidden" name="engine0" value="v1all">
   <input type="hidden" name="query" value="$QUERY">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
END

# Load the generated file in the browser.
firefox "file://$Work/load.html"

# Firefox returns immediately, so we want to give it a couple
# of seconds to actually read the page we generated,
# before we exit (and our page vanishes).
sleep 2
```

All that changes is the chunk where we use Bash string operations to replace each `&` with `&amp;`, each `"` with `&#34;`, each `<` with `&lt;`, and each `>` with `&gt;`, so that the query string can be safely written as the `value` attribute of the hidden input named `query`. (Those four suffice. It is also important to do the ampersand first, because the subsequent replacements contain ampersands. Since we emit this as the *value* of a hidden input, the query string is not url-encoded; it's just normal HTML content, but without doublequotes (because the value itself is in doublequotes).)

The downside of auto-submitting POST requests is that you may need to update your auto-submitting HTML page every now and then, simply because the site can change the POST variable naming and internal URLs whenever they want.

Answer (score 2):

Based on included Firefox [Marionette automation driver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette). Install the official python bindings:

```
pip2 install --user marionette_driver
```

```python
#!/usr/bin/python2

from marionette_driver.marionette import Marionette
from marionette_driver import By

client = Marionette('localhost', port=2828)
client.start_session()
client.navigate("https://www.startpage.com/")

query = client.find_element(By.ID, 'query')
query.send_keys("Search Me")
submit = client.find_element(By.ID, 'submit1')

submit.click()
```

This scipt requires firefox is already running. Maybe you have to enable *Marionette* using the option `--marionette`.

Answer (score 0):

`lynx` doesn't support POST from command line

I see only these solutions :

1. use some web automation software, like selenium
2. choose your language and code your simple automation :

   > launch the browser passing  the URL on the cmdline

> wait a few second and simulate key press to fill the form fields

see for example http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Answer (score 0):

The [Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) may work for you (it's a flexible intercepting proxy, the name is unfortunate).  It gets attention on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zap

This naturally leads to the problem of specifying a proxy server from the command line.  Here's firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843340/firefox-proxy-settings-via-command-line#843366  - 
Chrome will take `--proxy-server=`**ip:port**