# Use xdg-open to set cookie or post data

Tags: xdg-open, cookie

I use debian with gnome, and I often use `xdg-open` to launch my broswer on differents websites.

I know `xdg-open` is intended to use system's default application for argument's registered purpose, be it open files, URLs, or any preferred application, but is there a way to tell xdg-open to tell my broswer `xdg-open 'https://example.com/' --cookie=/tmp/my/cookie`, or to change the verb used (use `POST`, and add data to the body of the request) ? (Which would presuppose some unified ways to set cookie or post data crossbroswer, which I doubt but /meh)

Comment: note to myself : : first idea : replace my firefox in default applications with a proxy, and make a double dispatch depending on used broswer, then use https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82597/where-does-firefox-store-its-cookies-on-linux

Comment: and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375857/how-to-pass-post-parameters-to-open-a-webpage-in-browser